# In a composition of two rotations, is the fixed point of the second rotation affected by the first?

Tags: geometry

Given two rotations (one around fixed point A, the other around fixed point B).

If I construct the composition of these two rotations $R_B\circ R_A$, is the fixed point of the second rotation affected by the first, or not?

I.e., would the second rotation use the original B as fixed point, or the rotated-around-A point B'?

Comment: Why the mention to degrees? Would the problem be any different if you had used radians? And what is Ra x Rb? Did you mena $R_a\circ R_b$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: Paraphrasing the part of a larger assignment that is puzzling me. (I am supposed to construct the fixed point of the compound rotation, which I know how to do).

Comment: @daniel: You mean the movements are given in *reverse* order of (visualized) execution?

Comment: Yes. For example if I have two functions, $f_1(x),f_2(x)$ and I do $f_1(x)$ and then $f_2(f_1)(x), $ that is $f_2 \circ f_1 (x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have asked the question in an informal way. I think you mean a composition of rotations, $A\circ B.$

Consider a disk rotated $\pi/4$ radians about its center. Now rotate the disk $\pi/4$ radians about any point P on the edge of the disk in a plane containing the center and P, but perpendicular to that of the disk. The center will not remain fixed.

So in general the answer is no, the composition of two rotations will not leave a fixed point of the first rotation fixed.

That does not mean you could not construct a composition that preserved a fixed point from the first rotation.

EDIT: to answer the question in your last line,the second rotation will operate on the results of the first rotation.

Comment: Your last line actually answers the thing that baffled me. That the second rotation will affect the fixed point of the first is self-explanatory (unless the points are identical...)

Comment: The exact instructions are, "given a rotation at fixed point A by $\alpha$ degrees, and a rotation at fixed point B by $\beta$ degrees, construct the fixed points of the movements $R_A \circ R_B$ and $R_B \circ R_A$, respectively." I know how to construct the fixed points of the composition, I was just fuzzy about how to construct the composition itself.

Answer (score 0):

If $R_\theta$ is a rotation matrix around the origin, and $A$ the fixed point to rotate about, then a point $P$ is taken to:

$$R_\theta(P-A)+A$$

so the composition of two rotations is generally non-commutative.

You need to specify whether $B$ is to be considered rotated or absolute.